# group with periodic normal subgroup of finite index is periodic

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $A$ be a group. We say that $A$ is **periodic** if there exists $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $a\in A$ : $a^m=a$.

Let $G$ be a group and $H\triangleleft G$ such that $[G:H]<\infty$.

Given that $H$ is **periodic**, prove that $G$ is **periodic**.

Comment: You might want to require $m > 1$ of course

Comment: More generally if $H$ is normal in $G$ and $G/H$ and $H$ are both uniformly periodic, then $G/H$ is also uniformly periodic. (I call "uniformly periodic" what you call "periodic", since the latter usually means that every element has finite order, which is weaker in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the projection map $G\rightarrow G/H$, for every $g\in G$, $p(g)^n=1$ since the order of $G/H$ is $n$, we deduce that $g^n\in H$. We have $g^{nm}=({g^n})^m=1$ since $g^n\in H$. We deduce that $nm$ is a period of $G$.

Comment: $g^{nm} = (g^n)^m = g^n$. However your proof still holds since that means that $g^{nm - (n - 1)} = g \Rightarrow n(m-1) + 1$ is a period